# Anyone else heard of coldfusion t-sql use database bug?

Tags: database, t-sql, sql-server-2008, coldfusion

On our admin of our company's production site, we have a little query dumping tool, and I unknowingly, in trying to get data from a database, different than the main one, used the use database command.

And here's the kicker, it then made every coldfusion page with it's query instantly fail.

since it somehow caches that use database command.

Has anyone else heard of this weird bug?

How can we stop this behavior?

If i use a "use database" command, I want that to only exist as far as the current query i am running, after i am done, to go back to the normal database usage.

This is weird and a potentially damaging problem.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kibbee is on the right track, but to extend that a little further with three possible workarounds:

1. Create a different DSN for use by that one query so the "USE DATABASE" statement would only persist for any queries using that DSN.
2. Uncheck "Maintain connections across client requests" in the CF admin
3. Always remember to reset the database to the one you intend to use at the end of the request. It kinda goes without saying that this is a very dangerous utility to have on your production server!

It's not a bug nor is it really unexpected behavior - if the query is cached, then everything inside the cfquery block is going along for the ride. Which database platform are you using?

Comment: Is there any performance hit to disabling this checkbox? Considering that we may be running other sites & databases on the same server.

Comment: sure, there's a hit. unless you're in a high traffic environment it's negligible for most apps.

Answer (score 2):

I imagine that this has something to do with connection pooling.  When you call close, it doesn't close the connection, it just puts it back into the pool.  When you call open, it doesn't have to open a new connection, it just grabs an existing one from the pool.  If you change the database that the connection is pointing to, ColdFusion may be unaware of this.  This is why some platforms (MySQL on .Net for instance) reset the connection each time you retrieve it from the pool, to ensure that you are querying the correct database, and to ensure that you don't have any temporary tables and other session info hanging around.  The downside of this kind of behaviour, is that it has to make a round trip to the database, even when using pooled connections, which really may not be necessary.